# is there any method to take input from users and store it in array using inquirer in typescript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, npm, inquirer

I am trying to take input from users using npm inquirer like student info data and want to store it in array.
Language TYPESCRIPT

i am trying to build student registration form in typescript
I am using inquirer npm package for taking user's input.
Remember i am not using database for this project it is an assignment

Comment: Hi Sumama! To get more help here, please read [hot to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Specifically, show some code that you have tried so far, and describe exactly what part of that code isn't doing what you expect. You can [edit] your question to include more information.

Comment: The [inquirer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/inquirer) package provides a `inquirer.promt` method which takes an array of questions and returns an object with the answers. You can then convert this object into an array with [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.